# C++ static compile error using templates

Tags: c++, templates

I have

```
template < typename threadFuncParamT >
class ThreadWrapper
{
public:
    static int ThreadRoutineFunction(void* pParam);
    int ExecuteThread();

    ThreadWrapper(ThreadPool<threadFuncParamT> *pPool);

};

template<typename threadFuncParamT>
int ThreadWrapper<threadFuncParamT>::ThreadRoutineFunction(void* pParam)
{
    ThreadWrapper<threadFuncParamT> *pWrapper = reinterpret_cast<ThreadWrapper<threadFuncParamT>*>(pParam);
        if(pWrapper != NULL)
{

        return pWrapper-ExecuteThread(); // Error here.
    }

    return 0;
}

template < typename threadFuncParamT >
ThreadWrapper<threadFuncParamT>::ThreadWrapper(ThreadPool<threadFuncParamT> *pPool)
{
    ThreadWrapper<threadFuncParamT>::m_pThreadPool = pPool;
    m_tbbThread = new tbb::tbb_thread(&(ThreadWrapper<threadFuncParamT>::ThreadRoutineFunction), this);
    if (m_tbbThread->native_handle() == 0)
    {
        delete m_tbbThread;
        m_tbbThread = NULL;
        // TODO: throw execption here or raise assert.
    }
}
```

I am getting error as below
Error   1   error C2352: 'ThreadWrapper::ExecuteThread' : illegal call of non-static member function

I am compiling on VS2010.

Can any one help me here how to get clear the error.

Thanks!

Comment: you have a typo, you mean to have `pWrapper->ExecuteThread()`, correct?

Comment: That is such an obvious error, I am compelled to ask, did you even check once what the compiler error is trying to tell you?

Comment: Is that too obviously? Have you got any problems to understand this error?

Comment: Since the compiler complains about a *call*, I assume that SO's formatting ate the '>' character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the ">"
It's

```
pWrapper->ExecuteThread()
```

not

```
pWrapper-ExecuteThread()
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your error line

```
return pWrapper-ExecuteThread(); // Error here.
```

misses an `>`; it should read

```
return pWrapper->ExecuteThread(); // Error here.
```

You're getting such a strange compile error since it's trying to perform a subtraction; the pointer `pWrapper` is treated as an integer, and the value returned by calling `ExecuteThread()` (which yields an `int`) is subtracted from that. However, `ExecuteThread()` is neither a global function nor a static member function - hence the compiler complains.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the > on the call.   You want `return pWrapper->ExecuteThread();`

Answer (score 0):

You can't call static member function with that syntax. Try doing the following instead:

```
static_cast<ThreadWrapper*>(pParam)->ExecuteThread();
```

Maybe superfluous, but an explanation: functions that are entry points for threads cannot be instance methods, they must be file-scope function or static methods. The common idiom is to pass a void pointer to a static/global thread startup routine, cast that pointer to the proper class type and use it to call the actual instance method that will be executed in anothre thread.